# Using wordpress database for codeigniter except blogging

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

I am looking to integrate wordpress with codeigniter so that I can use the wordpress database in codeigniter and if possible I can use wordpress authorization mechanism as well.

I am not sure if it is possible at all.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a library for my requirement to bridge codeigniter with wordpress. I have put it in forums. Please read the steps carefully to integrate it. Hope that helps.

You can find that library [Here](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/230948/)